# ng-class is added to custom element, but the css style is not being applied

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My directive is of the format

`<mydir ng-class = "{'elHidden': test == test}" > </mydir>`

in my controller, I have defined `$scope.test = true`;

and in the CSS, I have defined the `elHidden` class style.

Is there anything wrong with my syntax?

Comment: `test == test` is always `true`.

Comment: @dfsq : Yes, I know that. Why is elHidden not applied in spite of it being true is my question.

Comment: Your directive probably strips off `ng-class`.

Comment: @m59 : I have not written any code to strip off ng-class. So how would this be likely?

Comment: Code for directive would help. Seems ok so far.

Comment: Are you positive the class is NOT applied? Inspect the element itself. It could be there, but the style isn't being applied.

Comment: On your directive, do you have replace: false in the declaration? If not, it will remove the bloody original element and replace it with your template. You need to make sure that replace is not true.

Comment: @aaronfrost actually, `replace: true` will keep `ng-class`. See the demo in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your condition is redundant (it's always true), the problem seems to be that your style is not being applied to your custom `mydir` element. As it is not a standard element, the browser doesn't recognize it and there won't be any default styles applied. In **[this example (click)](http://jsbin.com/AzifiFa/10/edit)**, the element on the screen has a class that applies a red background, but it is not applied unless you add `display: block` to the class.

You can add the necessary css to make your element work properly or use `replace: true` in the directive and replace the element with a standard one. **[Demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/AzifiFa/11/edit)**

Comment: Yeah, this was the problem. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<mydir style="display:block" ng-class="{'elHidden':test }"> </mydir>
```

Comment: This does not work either. elHidden is not applied in-spite of it's value being true. That is my question.

Comment: Paste your controller code. May be you are change value test which is in diff scope.